# Magento 2 : Admin Side mapping layout

Tags: magento2

I am implementing a module for salesforce integration in Magento 2. I want to map Salesforce fields with Magento fields(it will be dropdown list, from which user going to select field) as shown in the image. I am new in Magento 2. Does anyone help me with an example?
[sample layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfXjw.png)

Comment: Hello, welcome to stack overflow! IMO, this question is pretty vague and is unlikely to get constructive answers. What have you tried? What are your holdups? What language are you trying to implement this in? What are your requirements? What type of fields? 

I would recommend starting with the Magento REST API (https://devdocs.magento.com/redoc/2.3/) and the Salesforce REST API (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_what_is_rest_api.htm).

Comment: I am implimenting in Magento 2 using PHP language. Integration connection is done with salesforce. I have fetched Object fields from salesforce and There are separate field list of Magento Objects. I am trying to create layout in Magento 2 backend. Which will list All the fields from Salesforce and Infront of each field dropdown will be there. It will map accordingly